# Take a String with any number of words and store the words in different string variables?

Tags: c++, string

My aim is to do this in C++:
1. Let the user enter a line with any number of words.
2. Split the line into different words.
3. Store those words into separate string variables.

I know we can split the words of string using **istringstream** object.
**But my question is how to store them in DIFFERENT string variables?**. I know that it is not possible to create an *array of strings*.

Also, how to detect the end of string in a string stream, just like eof() marker in filestream?

Comment: Possible approach: 1. create an array of pointers to strings 2. store pointers of each variables to store the words to the array 3. store strings read to where each element of the array poinys at

Comment: "I know that it is not possible to create an *array of strings*." This is just a limitation for this task, isn't it?

Comment: **It is possible** to create array of strings in C++ (`char*`, `basic_string<T>`). You can use `sregex_token_iterator` to split an input string by regex.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Since you're already using the standard library, why not use a vector?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <vector>
#include <string>

std::string input = "abc def ghi";
std::istringstream ss(input);
std::string token;
std::vector<std::string> vec;

while(std::getline(ss, token, ' ')) {
    vec.push_back(token);
}  
//vec now contains ['abc', 'def', 'ghi']
```

Comment: `vec.push_back(std::move(token));` :-)

Comment: finally, along with 3 DOWNVOTES, i have an answer!!

Answer (score 1):

You have various options:

1. <strike>You can have an array of pointers to string; however, you need to know how many words there are in advance.</strike> **UPDATE:** As pointed out by @Blastfurnace this option is prone to errors and should be avoided.
2. You can use a [vector](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector) (or any other [container](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container)) to store them.

To get the words you can use a while loop and the extraction operator, it will automatically stop when you reach the end of your string.

Example:

```
istringstream iss(str);
string word;
while(iss >> word) {
    /* do stuff with the word */
}
```

Comment: I am very new to C++. Can you explain how do i create pointers pointing to each string>

Comment: @Andrew You only need to get the address of the string; for example, you have `string str = "hello world"` you will have to put the '&' before the variable name to get the address of that string. In this case `string* ptrStr = &str` will suffice.

Comment: @AndrewBond: You don't want an array of pointers. It can be done but it's error prone and more complicated than using a standard library container.

Comment: @Rodolfo: The example in your comment works for a single string. Do you think that makes sense for an arbitrary number of strings?

Comment: @Blastfurnace, yes, I may have made a mistake there; regardless, it is safer to use a vector.

Comment: @Rodolfo: I agree, if you start down the path of implementing your own dynamic array you just end up reinventing `std::vector`. People learning C++ should start with the standard library and save pointers for much later.

Comment: @Blastfurnace I will update the answer to reflect that.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/97924/discussion-between-rodolfo-and-blastfurnace).

Answer (score 0):

Yes I'm answering my Own Questions, after drawing conclusion from various above answers and comments. I'll answer in form of code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>
#include <string>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
string str, word;
vector<string> myVector;
getline(cin, str);
stringstream iss(str);
while(iss >> word)
     myVector.push_back(word);
}
```